# Unable to create external files directory - ANDROID

Tags: android, file

Here is my code and the error below.  I get an error in the logs saying Unable to create external files directory.

```
String downloadURL = getString(R.string.download_URL);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadURL);
DownloadManager.Request request = new Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(Request.NETWORK_WIFI | Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setTitle("Android Jelly Bean's Pic Download");
request.setDescription("Android Jelly Beans Pic Download using Download Manager");
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),    
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "abc.png");
downloadReference = dm.enqueue(request);
```

The line which has the error is 
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "abc.png");

```
12-05 18:51:55.436: W/ApplicationContext(1049): Unable to create external files directory
12-05 18:51:55.436: D/AndroidRuntime(1049): Shutting down VM
12-05 18:51:55.446: W/dalvikvm(1049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): java.lang.NullPointerException: file
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:441)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationFromBase(DownloadManager.java:504)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadManager.java:466)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.example.downloadmanagerapplication.DownloadManagerActivity.startDownload(DownloadManagerActivity.java:93)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.example.downloadmanagerapplication.DownloadManagerActivity$1.onClick(DownloadManagerActivity.java:115)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-05 18:51:55.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: One of my android colleagues reported that there are known issues with the download manager and advised me against using it. Just a heads up.

Comment: @GrahamSmith please suggest some alternative to downloadmanger, currently I am facing issues like can't write to internal memory extra.

Answer (score 11):

In order to save/write the data into file or create/remove directories, you must have to set "usage" permission in `manifest` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Sample : [Android DownloadManager](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)

Comment: oops sorry forgot to add I have these permissions
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: the problem was that the virtual device was created without sd card memory allocation.

Comment: What if the target device doesn't have a SD card? The app should still work, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can you try something like:

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);`

Instead of:

`request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Context, Type, Path)`